# Can't change webmin port?

Tags: webmin

I'm using the code

```
sudo nano -w /etc/webmin/miniserv.conf
```

to change Webmin's port in putty but it's saying command not found. Any suggestions?

```
:~# sudo nano -w /etc/webmin/miniserv.conf
sudo: nano: command not found
```

Comment: What's it saying exactly? I'd suggest editing the question to include (a copy/paste) exactly what you're inputting and exactly what it's replying with.

Comment: I havn't added or touched any of the accounts or it's settings. I'm using Ubunut 13.04 same error when removing sudo

Comment: @zarch can you please accept my answer as its solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Install nano then , `sudo apt-get install nano`

but AFAIK nano will be installed by default in every Ubuntu.

you can use other alternatives also.If you have GUI then

```
sudo gedit /etc/webmin/miniserv.conf
```

else you can use `vim` also.

Comment: @zarch if its helped you please accept it.